# Django advanced searching

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset

I was hoping that somebody could give me advice on what i'm trying to do. I have created a search engine for my application but i would like to take it to the next level.
Here's my current query method :

```
def search(self, query=None) :
    qs = self
    if query is not None :
        qs = qs.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(tags__name__icontains=query)).distinct()
    return qs
```

I would also like to return objects with similar names. For example, if i have an object named "Child" and the query is "Children", the search won't return my object. Is there to compare the number of similar charcaters.

I hope that you understand my question, considering how terrible my english is.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If the object is `Children`, then it will return this if you query with `Child`.

Comment: You can work with a search system like elasticsearch. Django-haystack has support for this: https://knowpapa.com/haystack-elasticsearch/

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem. Will look it up. (In my example i queried with Children).

Comment: ah, but then you wrote it the other way around in your question.

Comment: Yes you're right sorry. I should change it.